# Gmail blocks my mail (marked as spam)

Tags: gmail

Since i changed to another VPS server my mail is blocked when i sent it to a Gmail account

this is the error mail form Gmail :

```
his message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  wyannah1993@gmail.com
    SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
    host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2a00:1450:4013:c01::1b]:
    550-5.7.1 [2a01:238:43fb:cf00:3514:6d04:249e:ee45      12] Our system has
    550-5.7.1 detected that this message is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the
    550-5.7.1 amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please
    550-5.7.1 visit
    550-5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for
    550 5.7.1 more information. vp7si7215736wjc.112 - gsmtp

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

Return-path: <info@revolutionweb.nl>
Received: from mail-la0-f53.google.com ([209.85.215.53])
        by develstag01.stylehosting.eu with esmtpsa (TLSv1:RC4-SHA:128)
        (Exim 4.76)
        (envelope-from <info@revolutionweb.nl>)
        id 1XjYmg-0000ps-6b
        for wyannah1993@gmail.com; Wed, 29 Oct 2014 20:19:54 +0100
Received: by mail-la0-f53.google.com with SMTP id mc6so3105595lab.26
        for <wyannah1993@gmail.com>; Wed, 29 Oct 2014 12:19:53 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.112.169.6 with SMTP id aa6mr13783081lbc.29.1414610393670;
 Wed, 29 Oct 2014 12:19:53 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.25.39.193 with HTTP; Wed, 29 Oct 2014 12:19:53 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Wed, 29 Oct 2014 20:19:53 +0100
Message-ID: <CABS0uggkETx98bV1OypdB1zQZp=Lb+DEsJb7gEYd5=EXVRWTrA@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Even een test bericht
From: Ricardo van Laarhoven <info@revolutionweb.nl>
To: Wyannah Prikanowski <wyannah1993@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a11c38e9602ade4050694a615

--001a11c38e9602ade4050694a615
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hoiu wyannah,

ik kan geen mails sturen...... ik moet even testen of dit geen spam is..


dus darom typ ik maar een stuk langer

=C3=ADk hoop dat deze wel aankomt..

--=20
Met vriendelijke groet,

Ricardo van Laarhoven
www.revolutionweb.nl
info@revolutionweb.nl
06 18 36 50 18
Kvknr:   58325239
BTWnr: NL216018237B01
IBAN: NL07 INGB 0008 5382 22

--001a11c38e9602ade4050694a615
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<div dir=3D"ltr">Hoiu wyannah,<div><br></div><div>ik kan geen mails sturen.=
..... ik moet even testen of dit geen spam is..</div><div><br></div><div><b=
r></div><div>dus darom typ ik maar een stuk langer=C2=A0</div><div><br></di=
v><div>=C3=ADk hoop dat deze wel aankomt..<br clear=3D"all"><div><br></div>=
-- <br><div dir=3D"ltr"><div><div><div><div><div><div>Met vriendelijke groe=
t,<br><br></div>Ricardo van Laarhoven<br></div><a href=3D"http://www.revolu=
tionweb.nl" target=3D"_blank">www.revolutionweb.nl</a><br></div><a href=3D"=
mailto:info@revolutionweb.nl" target=3D"_blank">info@revolutionweb.nl</a><b=
r>06 18 36 50 18<br></div>Kvknr:=C2=A0=C2=A0 58325239<br></div>BTWnr: NL216=
018237B01<br></div>IBAN: NL07 INGB 0008 5382 22<br></div>
</div></div>

--001a11c38e9602ade4050694a615--
```

Comment: Your VPS server IP is probably blacklisted.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mail server setup.

Comment: Have you checked your new VPS' IP on blacklists, etc?

Comment: Kinda weird to lock it, after another admin moved it here... :)

Comment: Not sure why this was moved to Webmasters, it should probably go to Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

This is because they mark it as spam (they're kinda telling you that allready), Gmail is very strict.

There are a lot of factor which decide if something is spam or not. Some words add points, embedded images do etc etc.
There are also factors which decrease the points you get, like a whitelisted hoster, setting up an SPF record or a DKIM.

The difference between spam and notspam is rather sensative. Could be that because your new host has a small increase in points (and increase is bad), or your previous hoster made a decrease in points.

- [All About Spam](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test/) is a great tool. You mail them, you get a rapport what you did right/wrong
- [This spamassassin list](http://spamassassin.apache.org/tests_3_2_x.html) is great to read, at least once. They indicate the pentalties/bonusses.

Answer (score 1):

Mxtoolbox says your server has a DNS mismatch, which is a flag used to detect spam. So it could be due to the "develstag01" they are using instead of "vsrv02": http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=smtp%3a85.214.116.105&run=toolpage

Both resolve to 85.214.116.105 but its wonked somewhere - Not sure how you're set up, but that would be a starting point to check out.

Comment: Also, you appear to be connecting to Gmail over IPv6, so you should make sure you have the proper DNS entries for those addresses, as well.