# Why my emails go to spam

Tags: email, smtp, https

Now dont get me wrong, i did everything i possible can to ensure that my smtp server is GOOD, i use high quality content so this is not content issue.

i never sent email to anyone besides my self for testing, and its all going to spam.

i have DKIM/SPF/_dmarc, google-dns-verification, PTR/Reverse proxy or w/e it called, it all set 100% working and i can see in gmail on the source tab that all PASS.

i checked my server on multiple testing websites such as:
https://www.mail-tester.com/
and got 9.2

i checked that my IP is NOT blacklisted and its not.

i did everything i possible can to ensure my emails are OK but gmail still decides to throw me into spam (i tried to sent to 4-5 accounts not to one account only )

this is my email server - 
teamsvoice.com / mail.teamsvoice.com

i installed iredmail included working SSL certificates
anyone can think of Anything i haven't thought about?

Comment: Gmail is a constant problem. You are not alone.

Comment: See also: [Gmail blocks my mail (marked as spam)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71516/gmail-blocks-my-mail-marked-as-spam)